# If there is no destination does light actually get emitted?

Tags: optics, visible-light, variational-principle, cosmic-microwave-background

If the action of least principle says light needs a destination what happens when we shine a laser into the dark region of the microwave background radiation?

Alternatively, if we put a light source in a box made of a material that does not absorb light (a perfect reflector perhaps) and we could measure the energy use of the light device, would any light ever be emitted? In this case the box would be opened eventually so it's not as good as finding a real void.

[image]

Comment: If no light was emitted, we might detect it by measuring less power being drawn by the power supply. We then could measure directions where there was nothing to absorb light without leaving earth.

Comment: Action of least principle? Light needs a destination? It think you need to go back and rethink your question

Comment: Yes, principle of least action needs an initial condition and a final condition. But a photon heading off to infinity in a particular direction, is OK as a "final condition".

Comment: I think you might like the [Wheeler-Feynman Absorber theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory), and Cramer's [Transactional interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_interpretation) of QM.

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150994/25301

Comment: BTW, there are no dark regions in the CMB. Once you compensate for the Doppler shift due to Earth's motion, the CMB is *very* uniform, to around 1 part in 100,000. Those variations in the map in your question have been hugely amplified to make them visible.